# I have a list of pointers to objects of the items class. How do I access the object's functions?

Tags: c++, qt

I managed to write the data to the objects from the file. But I can't output this data to the console.

I already wrote-ListtForLoad.first().getName()
But can't get such access

I attach the full code of my program.

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QFile>
#include <QString>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QIODevice>
#include <QLinkedList>
#include <QTextStream>

class items : public QObject {

public:
    items(QString name, QString gryp){
        this->name = name;
        this->gryp = gryp;
    };
    QString getName() { 
        return name;
    }
    QString getGryp() { 
        return gryp;
    }
private:
    QString name;
    QString gryp;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    QLinkedList<QObject*> ListtForLoad;

    QFile fileIn("myfile.txt");
    QFile fileOut("myfileout.txt");

    int lineCount = 0;
    if (fileIn.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text)){
        lineCount = QTextStream(&fileIn).readAll().split('\n').count();
        fileIn.close();
    } 
    QString stringAllRead; 

    if(fileIn.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly)) {

        stringAllRead = fileIn.readAll();

        QStringList splitLines = stringAllRead.split("\r\n");

        for (int countItems = 0; countItems < lineCount; countItems++) {
            QStringList people = splitLines[countItems].split("&"); 
            ListtForLoad << new items( people[0], people[1] ); 
        }

        qDebug() << ListtForLoad.first().getName();

        fileOut.close();
    }
    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are storing `QObject*`'s in the `QLinkedList` so when you do the below, you get a `QObject*` back:

```
ListtForLoad.first()  // <- QObject* here
.getName()
```

To derefernce a pointer, you need to use `->` instead of `.` so:

```
ListtForLoad.first()->getName();
```

However, `QObject` doesn't have a `getName()` member function.

You should probably store your own type (`items`) in the list instead:

```
QLinkedList<items*> ListtForLoad;
```